# How to install Thinstation to local flash drive to the thinclient (i.e without cd rom)

Tags: thin-client, operating-system

We have a diskless thin client (it has it's local flash drive though)
Fujitsu Futro S-100.

I was able to boot from external USB flash drive and it's working just great.

How can I install Thinstation to it's own flash drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions in the [Thinstation FAQ](http://thinstation.sourceforge.net/CF-HOWTO-2.html) for creating a bootable flash drive.

Comment: Thank you! That was easy and helped me! I just opened the box and got special CF Card reader to format it and work with it via syslinux. Need to test (:

Comment: later, yes What I actually did is just I extracted CF disk from the device and installed Thinstation to it. Thanks again..HTH